# Use a variable in this javascript for loop

Tags: javascript, variables

I want the for loop to print out all the textboxes values, it doesn't work this way thought, how can I do it?

```
<script>
    current = x;

    for (var i = 0; i < current; i++) {    
        var num = document.calculator.textbox + i + .value;    
        document.write("<br>" + num);    
    }
</script>
<form name="calculator">
    <input type="text" name="textbox1">
    <input type="text" name="textbox2">
    <input type="text" name="textbox3">
    <input type="text" name="textbox4">
    <input type="text" name="textbox5">
    <!--...... infinite amount of textboxes-->
</form>
```

Comment: @Quentin, doesn't look like to me.

Comment: It would just be `read_prop(document.calculator, "textbox"+ 1);` Little extreme, but it would work. Nice explaination of [dot and bracket](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)

Answer (score 5):

Try to get them using brackets:

```
var num = document.calculator[ 'textbox' + i ].value;
```

So generally you can access object by two ways:

1. Via dots: `myObj.myProp`
2. Via brackets: `myObj[ 'myProp' ]`

Both ways are equal, but in second you can use variables + string concatenations, etc.

Comment: Hm, not sure why this was downvoted - it's the correct way to do it. You should add a quick explanation that you can use the `[]` array syntax to reference object keys

Comment: Weird, it doesn't work if i is set to 0..

Comment: because you have no input with an id of zero in your example code...

Comment: @user2468350 I've just showed to you how you can access objects via brackets. The rest you should write by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it. I used classes instead of ids. This way it's much easier to add more inputs as you won't have to worry about incrementing the ids and changing the `x` var.

http://jsfiddle.net/NXPKh/2/

```
var tbs = document.calculator.getElementsByClassName('textbox');

for (var i = 0; i < tbs.length; i++) {
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body') [0];
    var br = document.createElement("br");
    var text = document.createTextNode(tbs[i].value);
    body.appendChild(br);
    body.appendChild(text);
}
```